# how to use selected value in mysql procedure in asp.net through c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures

> I have this stored procedure made on mysql: and i use these select -1 or select -2 in variable declare in asp so i could use switch case accordingly output by this procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Validate_User($Username NVARCHAR(20), $_Password NVARCHAR(20),out $UserId INT )

BEGIN

DECLARE  $UserId1 INT ;DECLARE $LastLoginDate DATE;DECLARE roles varchar(20);

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username=$Username) THEN

SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username=$Username AND _Password=$_Password; 

    IF  EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username=$Username AND _Password=$_Password) THEN

       SELECT $UserId= -1; #UserValidate    

    ELSE


        SELECT -2; #Password Wrong

    END IF;

ELSE 

        SELECT -3; #USERNAME DOES NOT EXIST

END IF;

END $$


DELIMITER ;

    enter code here
```

**C# Code**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    int userId; string roles;

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.CommandText = "Validate_User";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$Username", TextBox1.Text);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$_Password", TextBox2.Text);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("$UserId", MySqlDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    con.Open();

    dr=  cmd.ExecuteReader();

    userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["$UserId"].Value);//here i want to take output from mysql

    dr.Read();

    roles = dr["RoleId"].ToString();

    con.Close();

    switch (userId)

    {

        case -2:

           Label1.Text = "Username and/or password is incorrect."; 

           break;

        case -3:

            Label1.Text = "Account has not been Exist.";

          break;

        default:

            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, TextBox1.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2880), false, roles, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

            string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);

            if (ticket.IsPersistent)

            {

                cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;

            }

            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);


            Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl( 
                TextBox1.Text,  false));

            break;

    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: So what issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: All time i get null value in variable userId in c# code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for setting an `OUTPUT` parameter in MySQL is either one of the following:

```
SET $UserId = -1;
-- or
SELECT -1 INTO $UserId;
```

So your stored procedure should be as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Validate_User($Username NVARCHAR(20), $_Password NVARCHAR(20),out $UserId INT )
BEGIN
  DECLARE  $UserId1 INT; DECLARE $LastLoginDate DATE; DECLARE roles varchar(20);
  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username=$Username) THEN
    SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username=$Username AND _Password=$Password;
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username=$Username AND _Password=$_Password) THEN
      SET $UserId = -1; #UserValidate    
    ELSE
      SET $UserId = -2; #Password Wrong
    END IF;
  ELSE 
    SET $UserId = -3; #USERNAME DOES NOT EXIST
  END IF;
END
```

Then, your C# code must read the output result set before it attempts to access the `OUTPUT` parameters. You can know if any rows were returned by testing the return value of `dr.Read()`. (Also, this is an `IDisposable` object, so use a `using` block.)

```
using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    int userId; string roles;

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "Validate_User";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$Username", "user");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$_Password", "pass");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("$UserId", MySqlDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    con.Open();

    using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (dr.Read())
            roles = dr["RoleId"].ToString();
    }

    userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["$UserId"].Value);

    con.Close();

    switch (userId)
    {
    case -2:
    case -3:
        "Username and/or password is incorrect.".Dump();
        break;

    default:
        // FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = ...
        break;
    }
```

Finally, it's usually considered a bad idea to output whether or not an account exists, because that lets an attacker distinguish between "valid account but wrong password" and "invalid account"; it's best to just display "Incorrect username or password" for both cases.

Comment: Not getting any output in c# yet

Comment: I am getting 0 in everytime in userId

Comment: Sorry sir it was silly mistake on myside.  Code provided by you is working perfectly. Thanks a lot 

Answer (score 0):

Although this seems a little odd solution to me and I would do it differently, here goes: When using a reader on SP, it must be closed before you can retrieve the output parameter, so close the reader,  if you incist on using it.

E. I assume you have tested your SP to be  fully working priorly, I did not give it a glimpse.